# JavaScript listening headset physical keys

Tags: javascript

can listen to the physical keys of headphones by JavaScript, such as the previous song and next song switching function of airpods. Can JS listen

Comment: Trying to do this proves that it's impossible on a website

Comment: Best you can do is detect the generic multimedia keys and, even then, the page needs focus in order for it work. [Multimedia keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_key_values#multimedia_keys)